# Take new columns as output table - KDB

Tags: export-to-csv, kdb, import-from-excel

I have a query which returns results of data, which runs on a frequent basis. The new table will contain results of the old table as well but I only want to take whatever is in new in the most recent run of the new table and send that as an email. I already have the line for the email and trade data but just need a way to be able to:

- display the results of the new table to be emailed
- save the complete results of the new table to be used in the next run of the query

e.g.

Old results: `tbl`

```
| idx | name  | age | 
| 0   | Tom   | 30  |
| 1   | Jerry | 25  |
| 2   | Bob   | 30  |
| 3   | Ken   | 45  |
```

New results: `tbl`

```
| idx | name  | age | 
| 0   | Tom   | 30  |
| 1   | Jerry | 25  |
| 2   | Bob   | 30  |
| 3   | Ken   | 45  |
| 4   | Sam   | 40  |
```

output required:

```
| 4   | Sam   | 40  |
```

and then save the New results to be used in the next run

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

If the only changes between runs is that records are being appended onto the new table, you could just keep a variable denoting the last index seen and then select only those rows where `idx` is larger than that.

If the indexes are always increasing, this could be achieved using a query like

```
lastidx:exec last idx from tbl
select from tbl where idx>lastidx
```

If the idx values don't always increase monotonically, you could keep a count of the number of rows instead and only

```
lasti:count tbl
select from tbl where i>=lasti
```

This doesn't require saving the whole table in memory for use in the next iteration.

E.g to start with the old table had 4 rows so `lasti` = 4

```
q)tbl
idx name  age
-------------
0   Tom   30
1   Jerry 25
2   Bob   30
3   Ken   45

q)lasti
4
```

The new table comes in and running the command selects the new row

```
q)tbl
idx name  age
-------------
0   Tom   30
1   Jerry 25
2   Bob   30
3   Ken   45
4   Sam   40

q)select from tbl where i>lasti
idx name age
------------
4   Sam  40
```

`lasti` can then be updated to reflect the new count

```
q)lasti:count tbl
q)lasti
5
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can get this done, assuming the `idx` is the unique key :

```
q)old:([] idx:0 1 2 3; name:`T`J`B`K; age: 30 25 30 45)
q)new:old,enlist `idx`name`age!(4; `S;40)  //new output from your query

q)out:()
q)if[0<count i:new[`idx] except old[`idx] ; out:new i ; old:new]

q)out
idx name age
------------
4   S    40
```

Another way, if your new records are always added to the last of old records:

```
q)old:([] idx:0 1 2 3; name:`T`J`B`K; age: 30 25 30 45)
q)i:count old
q)new:old,enlist `idx`name`age!(4; `S;40) //new output from your query

q)out:()
q)if[i<c:count new  ; out:(i-c)#new  ; old:new; i:c]
q)out
idx name age
------------
4   S    40
```